# How can I allow a user adjust an NSSlider without pausing the application update loop?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa

**NOTE: Updated below...**

I have a cocoa desktop application which consists of a series of controls around a custom NSView. I am using displayLink to drive the updates.

When a user clicks on an NSControl (a slider, a button, a checkbox, a radio button) the application appears to freeze until the mouse is released. I can confirm in fact that the displayLink callback (getFrameForTime) is NOT firing during the time. If I create a timer, that also does not fire, both remain paused until the user releases the mouse, at which point the application resumes updating.

The control is bound, and if I update that value from another thread (for example, via a callback from a MIDI interface) the slider behaves as expected: it moves, the value updates and the application does not pause.

I feel like this should be a fairly obvious fix, but I'm stumped.

- Checking "continuous" in IB does as advertised: sends the values continuously, but still exhibits this behavior (preventing the UI update) until the mouse is released.
- This seems to be related specifically to mouseDown on NSControl? Why would this block, and do I really need to subclass all my UI elements to change this behavior (seems extreme)
- DisplayLink is in its own thread, so why mouseDown on the main thread block it?  If this is the case, given the injunction on updating the Cocoa UI from other than the main thread, how do I deal with it?

Any help much appreciated.

## Update

Per @Nikolai's comments below, I can confirm that using an NSTimer and adding it to NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode does NOT block. However, I would really like to use CVDisplayLink which (according to the documentation) runs in it's own thread and should not be blocked in this way. Unlike CADisplayLink, I cannot find a way to explicitly assign a runloop to CVDisplayLink (it seems it doesn't work that way), so perhaps the new question should be:

Why does CVDisplayLink block on NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode?

Comment: Can you post a minimal example project that showcases the described  behavior?

Comment: Sure, putting that together now...

Comment: Ok, project is here. Note that it is very minimal indeed, it doesn't display anything (watch the console for NSLog from timer and from displayLink) Also note that the slider is connected to nothing and does nothing: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/930604/Personal/DisplayLinkIssue.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test project shows that you are calling a view's `display` method from within the display link's callback.

When commenting the `display` message out, the display link is called continuously even while moving the slider.

So what goes wrong is that when the runloop goes into event tracking mode, the call to `display` on the display link's thread blocks until the mouse is released and the run loop goes back to default mode. You can easily confirm this by putting a log statement before the call and one after it.

Why exactly that happens is not clear to me. What is clear is that it's illegal to call a view's methods from a background thread. You have to trigger the view's display by dispatching a `setNeedsDisplay:` on the main thread:

```
static CVReturn MyDisplayLinkCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink, const CVTimeStamp* now, const CVTimeStamp* outputTime, CVOptionFlags flagsIn, CVOptionFlags* flagsOut, void* displayLinkContext)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [(__bridge MyCustomView*)displayLinkContext setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    });
    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks! 1. Weird. But... 2. To be honest I don't remember why I called display there (my code began as apple boilerplate and mutated a bit as I was working), I don't need it. Exceedingly grateful for all of your help, this has been irritating me for ages.

Comment: You are very welcome. This is one of the cases where [rubber ducking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) really helps. Sometimes the rubber duck is SO.

Comment: I just ordered a duck.:D And yeah... clearly starting at this code too long didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

When clicking on an NSControl the runloop mode goes from `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` to `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode`, as long as the mouse is down. That means that only run loop sources (display link) and timers fire that have been added to this mode.

You can add timers to any mode by using `-[NSRunLoop addTimer:forMode:]`. For a display link the equivalent method is `-[CADisplayLink addToRunLoop:forMode:]`.

To make your animation continue during event tracking you would do something like:

```
[myDisplayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                    forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in a good direction... This seems to describe the problem (and goes a long way to helping me understand what is going on) but I'm on OSX not iOs, so I'm using CVDisplayLink rather than CADisplayLink. CVDisplayLink https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVDisplayLinkRef/Reference/reference.html doesn't appear to offer a way to specify the runloop. I will keep digging.

Comment: @andrew Oh, I see. It's been quite some years since I used this on Mac OS and I was under the impression that Apple added a Cocoa way to use display links since. It's a lot easier on iOS with the nice `CADisplayLink`. If I remember correctly the `CVDisplayLink` used an own thread for the call back. I can't understand why a run loop should affect this. Sorry.

Comment: I can confirm this does solve the problem for NSTimers so I'm confident you diagnosed the problem, I'm just hung up on how to access the displayLink timer object on MacOS (digging through the docs now, but yes it seems less direct than it does with CADisplayLink... which is supposed to use its own thread. hrm. Maybe I'll just port everything to iphone ;) )